# How do I get the ID or Class of the content displayed using html () in the jQuery function?

Tags: html, jquery

I have problem with my code. 
This is my `index` page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Page INDEX -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page"></div> <!-- ID For LOADED from page getsoal -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getsoal.php',
            data: { page: 1 },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                /* Get konten from page getsoal */
                $('#page').html(data);
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
        $('.jawab').change(function () { /* Class jawab from page getsoal while loaded */
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        });
        $('#form').submit(function (e) { /* ID form from page getsoal while loaded */
            e.prevendDefault();
            /* SEND via AJAX */
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is page from `getsoal.php`

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="soal" value="1">
        <label for="jawab-1"><input type="radio" class="jawab" id="jawab-1" name="jawab" value="1"> A </label>
        <label for="jawab-2"><input type="radio" class="jawab" id="jawab-2" name="jawab" value="2"> B </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

My question is how can I get the ID or class that is on the `getsoal.php` page and give it an event on the `index` page using jquery? I use the `html()` function instead of `load()`, because if I use `load()`, the content of `soalpage.php` doesn't appear because it's blocked

Comment: html and load are not the same function. html only write the value to target element and load perform fetch operation. your problem is very ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `submit` handler is being set up in the wrong place (before `#form` is loaded). You need to move that to right after the HTML is loaded. You also have a typo: `prevendDefault()` should be `preventDefault()`. Your corrected code should read:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getsoal.php',
  data: { page: 1 },
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function (data) {
    /* Get konten from page getsoal */
    $('#page').html(data);
    console.log(data)

    // Now that .jawab and #form have been loaded, attach event handlers to them:
    $('.jawab').change(function () { /* Class jawab from page getsoal while loaded */
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });

    $('#form').submit(function (e) { /* ID form from page getsoal while loaded */
      e.preventDefault();
    /* SEND via AJAX */
    })

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve but if you want to append the content get from your ajax request to the `#page` div you can use append function of jquery in the success callback of your ajax function

```js
$("#page").append(data);
```